# How to use the index of selected data from one figure, to plot something in another figure?

Tags: visualization, data-visualization, bokeh, bokehjs

I have a scatter plot on one figure. I'd like to be able to select possibly multiple data points on the mentioned scatter plot, and plot a (possibly) multi-line timeseries chart on the other figure, based on the indexes of the selected data.

Pseudo code:

```
data = { x: [1,2,3], y: [1,2,3], time_series: [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]] }
figure1 = scatter_plot(x, y, select_enabled=True)
figure2 = multi_line_timeseries(figure1.indexes_of_selected_points)
show([figure1, figure2])
```

So if the `[1,1]` data point (index 0) is selected on figure 1, then the `[1,2,3]` timeseries (index 0) is plotted on figure 2. If multiple points are selected, then multiple timeseries are plotted.

A restraint is that the HoloViews library can't be used, due to it not supporting my platform.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Could you clarify on why HoloViews can't be used? As far as I know HoloViews should be supported on all platforms.

Comment: @philippjfr, HoloViews fails upon import on ARM with an LLVM error that says "external function __aeabi_unwind_cpp_pr0 could not be resolved". Here's a related thread concerning, fastparquet and numba: https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/3508

Comment: You might try uninstalling datashader and try again on ARM? I don't have any ARM platform I could test that on.

Comment: @JamesA.Bednar datashader is not installed. On linked thread someone reported that they didn't have this issue on their ARM device. I'm not sure what might be causing this.

Comment: Odd.  If fastparquet is installed on your system, maybe try uninstalling that.  HoloViews doesn't have any system code and does not use LLVM directly, so there *should* be no reason to run into issues with it.

Comment: @JamesA.Bednar, ha! Uninstalling fastparquet worked. Thank You, I would have never guessed the connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: I have opted to not support simultaneous multiple timeseries plotting, though that would be a trivial extension of this.

To use selected data point's index to determine what is to be plotted in another figure, you need to:

- put the relevant data (i.e. `x,y,timeseries` in the example) on one or multiple `ColumnDataSource`s;

  - I put the data to select and data that will be updated on different cds's, because I fear it might create a callback loop, though I've not tested this.
- create a `ColumnDataSource` which will act as source for the second figure that plots the timeseries;
- enable a selection tool, for example `TapTool` (`'tap'`);
- add a `CustomJS` callback to the `ColumnDataSource` that holds the selectable data points;
- parametrize that callback with the `ColumnDataSource` that holds the timeseries data;
- have the callback access indeces of selected data points;
- have the callback make required changes to the second figure's `ColumnDataSource`;
- call `cds_of_2nd_figure.change.emit()` before returning from the callback.

Code to illustrate:

```
cds = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x,y=y,timeseries=timeseries))
cds2 = ColumnDataSource(x_to_plot=[],u_to_plot=[])

def selection_callback(d=cds,d2=cds2):
    last_selected_ix = cb_obj.selected.indices[0]
    timeserie = d.data['timeseries'][last_selected_ix]
    x_to_plot = timeserie['x']
    y_to_plot = timeserie['y']
    d2.data['x_to_plot'] = x_to_plot
    d2.data['y_to_plot'] = y_to_plot
    d2.changes.emit()

# turn above function to js
selection_callback = CustomJS.from_py_func( selection_callback )

cds.callback = selection_callback
```

When some figure selects data from `cds`, the `timeseries[ix]` timeserie will be plotted on the figure/s that plot `cds2`, where `ix` is the index of the last selected data point from `cds`.

Relevant resource that has all the relevant information:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html#customjs-for-tools